# Mathematical formula on tax problem solving on php code

Tags: php

We have three variable inputs

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input name="a">
<input name="c">
<input name="f">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

okey, The mathematical code is the solution to this problem. a to the amount :c is equal to the number of years eg 10 : f to 25

---

So a is 200 and c is 10 and f is 25 These numbers are our input

---

So the math answers to this

```
x1= a*f/100
x2 = ((a-x1)*f)/100
x3 = ((a-x1-x2)*f)/100
x4 = ((a-x1-x2-x3)*f)/100
x5 = ((a-x1-x2-x3-x4)*f)/100
x6 = ((a-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5)*f)/100
x7 = ((a-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5-x6)*f)/100
x8 = ((a-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5-x6-x7)*f)/100
x9 = ((a-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5-x6-x7-x8)*f)/100
x10 = ((a-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5-x6-x7-x8-x9)*f)/100
```

please help for write php code. I used this for loop for

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
$c = $_POST['c'];
$f = $_POST['f'];

for ($i=1;$i<=$c;$i++){
$x = $a*f/100;
$x[$i] = ($a (-$x[$i][])*f)/100;
echo $x[$i];
echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post some code that you have already attempted to write to solve this problem, then we can help you.

Comment: Thank you. One issue I see is that you are missing $ in front of your f variable.

Comment: Also, I don't see an array declaration for $x

Comment: What do you think of converting this equation to php code?

Comment: If you're asking me to write code for you, I cannot do that. Stack Overflow is not intended to be a code writing serve.

Comment: Are you simply trying to write PHP code to echo the output in your second code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest way to required your output

```
<?php
    $a = $_POST['a'];
    $c = $_POST['c'];
    $f = $_POST['f'];
    $result = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++){
        $x = (($a-$result)*$f)/100;
        $result = $result + $x;
        echo $x."<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try to loop it over and over storing the results in an array, in this case in the `$x`.

The `echo` is just to show the logic, you can delete them.

```
<?php
$a = 200;
$c = 10;
$f = 25;

$x[] = $a*$f/100; //Assign first value, so $x[0] = 50

for ($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){ //$i < $c because array first index is 0

    $xIn = $a;
    echo 'x' . ($i+1) . ' = ((a'; //$i + 1 is just for printing.

    for ($i2=0;$i2 < $i;$i2++){
        echo '-x' . ($i2+1); //$i2 + 1 is just for printing.
        $xIn -= $x[$i2];
    }
    echo ')*f)/100';
    $x[$i] = ($xIn * $f) / 100; //Total.
    echo ' | Total = ' . $x[$i] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

You can paste the code here and test: http://phptester.net/

Comment: awesome! amazing job, tested!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below.

```
<?php
$a = 200;
$c = 10;
$f = 25;
$values = [];
echo '<pre>';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $c; $i++) {
    $diff = $a;
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $diff -= $value;
    }
    $values['x' . $i] = ($diff * $f) / 100;
}

print_r($values);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimum code needed to solve your problem...

```
 <?php
    $a = $_POST['a'];
    $c = $_POST['c'];
    $f = $_POST['f'];
    $x = [];
    $x[0] = $a*$f/100;
    $logic = $a;
    for ($i=1;$i<count($c);$i++){
     for ($j=$i-1;$j >= $i;$j--){

            $logic -= $x[$j];
        }

    $x[$i] = ($logic*f)/100;
    echo $x[$i];
    echo '<br>';
    }
    ?>
```